# Create a BaseView class in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a BaseView class in Kotlin , that all my childviews are going to extend.

My problem is inflating the Layout in the BaseView class because the layout resource id is provided too late to the BaseView constructor .

Here is my BaseView

```
 abstract class BaseView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context?,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : MaterialCardView(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {

    protected abstract val viewResourceId: Int
    protected abstract val needsRefresh: Boolean

    init {

        View.inflate(context,viewResourceId, this) // viewResourceId is not initialized here as yet
    }


    enum class State {
        DISABLED,
        LOADING,
        DONE,
        FAILED
    }
}
```

The problem is the well known "accessing non-final property in constructor". I had applied an exactly same strategy in Java previously and this used to work .

How would I go about this situation ? . I need to inflate my layout in the base. It makes sense to do so because the inflation is a common operation.

Is delegated property the way to go ?

EDIT: This is how my client looks

```
class StudentView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context?,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : BaseRegion(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {
    override val viewResourceId=R.layout.student_view
    override val needsRefresh=false

    init {
        context?.
            let {  setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context,R.color.colorAccent)!!)}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work when you're using a property with a backing field, as the initialization of that field happens in the constructor of the child class, which runs after the parent's constructor.

You can, however, use a computed property, which will get evaluated when the parent calls it, as expected:

```
override val viewResourceId: Int
    get() = R.layout.some_layout
```

Or you could define an abstract function, and override that, which would be essentially the same thing:

```
override fun getViewResourceId(): Int = R.layout.some_layout
```

---

On another note, using `@JvmOverloads` could be an issue in certain custom views, as calling any of the constructors generated for your own class will first delegate into the all-params constructor within the class, and then call the all-params constructor of the super, instead of each constructor calling into the super method with the matching amount of parameters. See [this article](https://blog.q42.nl/the-danger-of-assumptions-kotlin-with-android-custom-views-adb79bf2da45) (for example) for details on that.

Comment: zsmb13 I just edited my question to include my client class. I have overridden the property just as you suggested. In my base view my viewResourceId has 0 in it .

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right. This has to be either a function or a computed property, as a real property with a backing field wouldn't be initialized in time. I'll edit my answer in a moment.